# Paired t-test for different observed parameters - Should I use multiple compairaison's tetsing and how?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, paired-data

I have a group of rats that each go through two treatments: Control (No stimulation) and Laser stimulation.
For each treatment I obtain several number of parameters such as Attention score, number of correct responses, accuracy etc... the system records over 20 variables or so per session.

I am interested in about 8 or 10 of these. Since the same rat undergoes the two procedures I performed paired t-tests for each of the parameters I am interested in. Comparing the differences between control and laser treatments for each rat.

**I have been now asked by a reviewer to perform multiple comparison testing. My question is, is this necessary ? I am not comparing between parameters, I am singly interested in whether each relevant behavioral parameter is affected by laser stimulation on the rat.**

Furthermore, if it is necessary, would I have to correct for all the variables I collected (20 or so) or only the variables which i care about and I am reporting in the paper. The former seems like the appropriate manner but it appears to punish me for recording and presenting as many things as i could.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you probably have to do something about alpha error cumulation. If you perform 10 tests and the null was true then we expect 59% of such papers to come out p>.5 but 31.5 % of such papers with one falsely "significant", 7.5 % two falsely significant and so on.

```
> dbinom(0:10, size= 10, p = .05)
[1] 5.987369e-01 3.151247e-01 7.463480e-02 1.047506e-02 9.648081e-04 6.093525e-05 2.672599e-06
[8] 8.037891e-08 1.586426e-09 1.855469e-11 9.765625e-14
```

What exactly has to be done will depend on your paper. If you have 8 out of 10  "significant" results and all you want to show is that LASER stimulation does anything at all to rats, then you are fine.

If you want people to be convinced of every $p < .05$ there is, you probably need Bonferroni correction, which is good for your alpha error but bad for your beta error. Considerations whether alpha or beta errors are worse need to be done with knowledge in your field of research and may well lead to something that is not Bonferroni, like maybe reducing alpha form .05 to .01 as a compromise.

Some kind of omnibus test (in this case maybe MANOVA?) might help convincing peer reviewers and readers.

> The former seems like the appropriate manner but it appears to punish me for recording and presenting as many things as i could.

You should not be punished for working a lot. However there will be the question, whether you decided on those 8 to 10 measures before or after you knew their $p$-values. It will depend on your introduction whether you explain plausibly that taking only these 8 or 10 into consideration is an a priori sensible decision.
Study pre-registration is a great way to argue, less so statistical evaluation plans given to ethics committees or animal protection regulation offices or those who financed the study *before* the experiments were conducted.

Define primary and secondary endpoints in a way, that people believe you, you did it before looking at the results. Then care for alpha inflation only for the primary endpoints and clearly mark any significant secondary end point as only secondary.